# How to retrieve the mongodb query result from a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve the result of a db.collection query in the "/read/:id" route. When a user is found,the promise is fulfilled and status 'success' is sent. The data object is, however, empty.

Query:

```
const getDb = require('./connection').getDb,
    ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

readUser: async function(data) {
    let o_id = new ObjectId(data);
    await getDb().collection('users').find({ _id: o_id })
    }
```

Route:

```
const express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
queries = require('../db/queries');

router.get('/read/:id', (req, res) => {
queries.readUser(req.params.id)
    .then((user) => {
        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            data: user
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({
            status: 'error',
            data: err
        });
    });
})
```

res.json

```
{
    "status" : "success"
}
```

Could anybody explain how to successfully retrieve the data of the query?

Please find the project code [here](https://github.com/wassbeer/voting-app/tree/usersapi/services/users/src).

Thank you.

Comment: Why not returning anything from readUser function?

Comment: Where would you return? In the callback?

Comment: you are using await so no need to pass callback function just add return before await and it will return the data that you want.

Comment: The result with return await is:

`{
   "status" : "error", "data" : {}
}
`

Comment: can you once try passing callback and console.log the the data that you get inside the callback  function.

Comment: Yes. It is the cursor object.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/wassbeer/bb7a023d0b6b5e8d8d686707fa9cd4b3

Comment: The return is necessary, thank you! Please check my solution in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found a solution.

```
readUser: async function(data) {
            let o_id = new ObjectId(data),
                cursor = getDb().collection('users').find({ _id: o_id });
            return await cursor.next() // returns document result of collection.find() method
        }
```